# HTA format not working properly?

Tags: format

Interested in creating a HTA with specific functionality but can't seem to get things working/looking as they should. Is there a way to utilize either an ImageMap or DIVs containing images so that the mouse actions (hover/click/etc.) will work as they should? ImageMap is nice because I can just have a single image and the window recognizes the areas, but I can't get an image swap to occur on mouse actions. Is the image swap functionality not possible with ImageMap? I also tried utilizing pixel-exact dimensioning with DIVs, but there's always an issue with floats, clears, margins, etc., which makes it look like the images below. Is an HTA simply not capable of this functionality? If it's not, what would be the alternative?

Here's how it looks if I use an HTA...

[image: incorrect display]

Here's how it looks if I rename it to HTM...

[image: correct display]

````
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script language="vbscript">
   option explicit
   dim width, height, idtimer
   width=410
   height=225
   window.resizeto width, height
   window.moveto screen.availwidth\2-width\2, screen.availheight\2-height\2
   idtimer=window.settimeout("vbscript:window.close", 4000)
  </script>
  <style>
   * { font:12px "segoe ui", sans-serif; margin:0; padding:0; }
   div#container { height:225px; width:410px; }
   div#title { background-color:blue; border-left:1px solid blue; border-top:1px solid blue; color:#fff; float:left; height:26px; padding-top:6px; width:376px; }
   div#button { background-color:blue; border-top:1px solid blue; border-right:1px solid blue; color:#fff; float:left; height:32px; margin-left:377px; }
   span#titletext { background-color:blue; color:#fff; padding-left:6px; width:360px; }
   span#buttontext { background-color:blue; color:#fff; font-size:18px; padding-left:13px; width:32px; }
   div#main { clear:both; height:125px; width:410px; }
   div#graphic { background-color:#987; border-left:1px solid blue; float:left; height:125px; width:60px; }
   div#content { background-color:#abc; border-right:1px solid blue; float:left; height:125px; width:348px; }
   div#footer { background-color:#eee; border-left:1px solid blue; border-bottom:1px solid blue; border-right:1px solid blue; clear:both; height:40px; width:408px; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <hta:application applicationname="Index" id="Index" border="none" borderstyle="normal" caption="no" commandline="" contextmenu="no" icon="" innerborder="no" maximizebutton="no" minimizebutton="no" navigable="no" scroll="no" scrollflat="no" selection="no" showintaskbar="no" singleinstance="yes" sysmenu="no" systemmenu="no" version="" windowstate="normal" />
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="title"><span id="titletext">Index</span></div>
   <div id="button"><span id="buttontext">x</span></div>
   <div id="main">
    <div id="graphic"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
 </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: the windows builtin mshta.exe uses an old version of IE renderer (IE=5) by default, so there are fixes to do for CSS. You can specify different versions with meta tags to getter better CSS support, but newer versions of IE may require javascript instead of vbscript etc. Take a look at the answer here for some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19771582/7411885

Comment: IE is obsolete, the linked question is from 2013, I wouldn't be surprised it if this is a MS-only feature too, time to move on, isn't it???